# Linking button and text portion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting confused how to link the button of the navigation bar to the certain of the text of the same page of the website in HTML.

Comment: <a href="#divIdHere">Button Text</a> <div id="divIdHere"></div>

Comment: i do have this  :- 
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work and Experience</a>
      </li>
this is the button code that i write. When i try to link the button with certain portion of text of same page given by you it  is not working still.

Comment: See @Commercial Suicide 's answer for more details. He's included a snippet for you to see an example. The place you want it to scroll to has to have the same id as the link's href hash value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery plugin that does just that [Scroll To](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo). This can also be done with many other frameworks if you have restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, just use href `<a href="#target"></a>` to scroll, and id `<h1 id="target"></h1>` as a target:

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: violet;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#target">Scroll</a>
<div id="wrapper">
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  <h1 id="target">TARGET</h1>
</div>
```